# iOS adding a button from viewcontroller.m

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, button

So, I've been trying to learn the basics of Objective-C programming for iOS. Now I need to have a simple button placed in the frame along with a label. I got the label working but I'm not sure what's wrong with the button code.

The code:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 25, 275, 60)];
label.text = test;//@"I am learning Objective-C for the\n very first time!";
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
//label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping; //iOS 6 only
[self.view addSubview:label];

UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 100, 275, 40)];
button.titleLabel.text = @"Hello";
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

The button isn't showing up...

Comment: @rmaddy the button wont display...?

Comment: A tip: if a view won't appear for an unknown reason, try setting `view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]`.

Comment: @drummerb the red shows up but the button may not be styled properly? Im not sure...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical way to create a button is this:

```
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [btn setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(25, 100, 275, 40);
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:btn];
```

Then the `someMeothod:` would be:

```
- (void)someMethod:(UIButton *)sender {
    // handle button press
}
```

Comment: ill try this out :) nothing in objective-c seems straight forward

Comment: This has nothing to do with Objective-C. This is a function of the UIKit framework. Creating a button takes a certain amount of setup.

Comment: where would the method go on the page? In the didviewload section?

Comment: The `someMethod` (please give it a better name) goes in your class implementation, not inside any other method.

Comment: ok, thanks, right now I am using button_method :)

Answer (score 2):

dot notation can be problematic.  Use this to set the title:

```
    [button setTitle:@"myTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: no, its still not showing up

Comment: I've posted the entire code that I'm using... what do i need to do to fix this?

Comment: The label shows up, but not the button???  Try using alloc init (without setting the frame) and see if it shows.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 30);
[myButton setTitle:@"normal" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"selected" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
myButton.titleLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

Comment: umm this is my code anyway...

Comment: sorry, still didnt work? im not sure how to debug properly in objective-c its my first time ever working on it.

Comment: let me try it out, it looks like it may work :)

Comment: @self You should use the proper `UIButton` methods to set the button's title text and title colors for the different states.

Comment: the text isn't showing up though